# Modify excel custom variable with DocumentFormat.OpenXml C#

Tags: c#, excel

Following the steps from this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/open-xml/how-to-set-a-custom-property-in-a-word-processing-document), I have used the following code to modify just one custom property from a .xslm file (excel with macros):

```
var newProp = new CustomDocumentProperty();
newProp.VTInt32 = new VTInt32("1");
newProp.FormatId = "{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}";
newProp.Name = "CurrentVersionExported";

using (var document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(excelPath, true))
{
     var props = document.CustomFilePropertiesPart.Properties;

     var prop = props.Where(p => ((CustomDocumentProperty)p).Name.Value == "CurrentVersionExported").FirstOrDefault();

     // If the property exists, get the return value  and then delete the property.
     if (prop != null)
     {
          prop.Remove();
     }

     // Append the new property, and fix up all the property ID values. 
                  
     props.AppendChild(newProp);
     int pid = 2;
     foreach (CustomDocumentProperty item in props)
     {
          item.PropertyId = pid++;
     }
     props.Save();
}
```

It works well but there are two things that I do not understand:

1. What is the pid? i believe it is the property ID, but I do not understand why it has to be 2 initially.
2. How should I know the initial format ID from my property? My excel does not have an XML schema so I have used the format ID from the post I linked before, I do not know if it is wrong or not to use that one.

Comment: you already use the ID 1 here: newProp.VTInt32 = new VTInt32("1");

Comment: the item.PropertyId is a uniqe ID of all your objects

Comment: @ChrisBerlin that "1" in newProp.VTInt32 is the value I want to set in the custom property

So i can set the initial pid as 1, 2 or whatever I want I suppose isn't it?